# change background color of UITableViewCell on tap on UIButton inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` who contains 3 `UIButtons` and I want that when I tap one button, the background of my cell change. But when I tap a button all cells in my `UITableView` change their background and not only the cell who has the button inside it.

Custom Cell (.h)

```
@interface SCActionsViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *thanksButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *commentsButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *reButton;


@end
```

Custom Cell (.m)

```
#define TEXT_BUTTON_SIZE 25
@implementation SCActionsViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorLight];
    _thanksButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width/3, actionsCellHeight)];
    _commentsButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width/3, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width/3, actionsCellHeight)];
    _reButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width*2/3, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width/3, actionsCellHeight)];

    _thanksButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:TEXT_BUTTON_SIZE];
    _commentsButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:TEXT_BUTTON_SIZE];
    _reButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:TEXT_BUTTON_SIZE];

    [_thanksButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAThumbsOUp] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_commentsButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FACommentsO] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_reButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FARetweet] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_thanksButton setTitleColor:[UIColor sGreen] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [_reButton setTitleColor:[UIColor sGreen] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [self addSubview:_thanksButton];
    [self addSubview:_commentsButton];
    [self addSubview:_reButton];
}

@end
```

SCViewDataSource (TableviewDataSource)

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.posts.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        SCActionsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SCActionsViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.tableView = tableView;
        cell.indexPath = indexPath;
        [cell.thanksButton addTarget:(SCViewController *)tableView.delegate action:@selector(touched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        return cell;
}
```

SCViewController.m

```
-(void)touched:(UIButton *)button{
    NSLog(@"indexPath : %@",((SCActionsViewCell *)button.superview).indexPath);
    ((SCActionsViewCell *)button.superview).backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

In this case when I tap thanksButton in a cell all the cells change their background to blueColor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out by my own : don't use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]` but `[[CustomCell alloc] init]` and create your `init` function in your custom cell class.

Like this every cells will be a new object.

Answer (score 0):

(Try this) Updated you touched methood using following code.

```
-(void)touched:(UIButton *)button{
    NSLog(@"indexPath : %@",((SCActionsViewCell *)button.superview).indexPath);
    ((SCActionsViewCell *)button.superview).contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Comment: not working, addTarget must be self in your case and it's change all the background of the cells....

Comment: Add one more property for cell called `@property BOOL tapped;` then, when button is tapped set it to YES and show blue background only for tapped == YES.
`cell.tapped = YES`

Comment: you can add Tap Gesture Recognizer

Answer (score 0):

Add a property (maybe an `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray`) for tracking which indexPaths have been tapped already. Creating a new cell every time is very expensive. I suggest you don't abandon `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]`.

You could try this:

```
- (void)touched:(UIButton *)sender {
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = ((SCActionsViewCell *)button.superview).indexPath;
  [self.thankedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
}
```

Then you can set the background color accordingly:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  SCActionsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SCActionsViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.tableView = tableView;
  cell.thanked = [self.thankedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];
  cell.indexPath = indexPath;
  [cell.thanksButton addTarget:(SCViewController *)tableView.delegate action:@selector(touched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  return cell;    
}
```